# is returning div from Ajax request secure?

Tags: php, ajax

this is whats i have been using but i noticed no one else is using it, which is return HTML from ajax request.

```
//prepared statement
while($stmt->fetch()){
   @$row .= '<div class="holder"> 
                 <div class="head">'.htmlspecialchars($head).'</div>
                 <div class="title">'.htmlspecialchars($title).'</div>
                 <div class="body">'.htmlspecialchars($body).'</div>
             </div>';
}
echo json_encode(array('sucLog' => @$row));
```

this is what most people i see is doing. then they use jquery or Javascript to format the html

```
$json = new stdClass();
$json->head = $head;
$json->title =  $title;
$json->body = $body;
echo json_encode($json);
```

am just wondering if my method is wright or not

Comment: JSON gives you more control over the data later by just changing the front-end and gives a nice separation from front-end and back-end which is what display typically is. Though this question is entirely too open and too opinion based to really make it a good question for this site imo. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a security issue. Both methods are used, as you've seen, but really the second method is preferable because it ensures your back-end is decoupled from your front end.

If you follow the principle of SOLID code, the S means "singe responsibility". In your example, that means the PHP code should focus on reading and writing raw data, and leave it to the presentation layer to make that look however it needs to – HTML in this case.

If you decide in the future that you want to support Apple News format, Facebook Instant Articles, etc, etc, having your back-end return pure data is a smart thing, because you can create other renderers that work with the same basic data format.

So: I would suggest you return pure data from your PHP code, then have your front-end (jQuery, React, etc) convert that to HTML.